# Resize Visio drawing to fit paper size and print on one page

Tags: printing, microsoft-visio, drawing

My Visio 2016 flowchart no longer fits the background page and is not resizing to first on one page even though my page setup settings are to fit 1x1 page.  How can I reset this?

Visio Flowchart Screenshot:
[image: Visio Flowchart/Drawing]

Print Preview Screenshot:
[image: Print Preview]

Answer (score 4):

Go to **Design** tab, open **Page Setup** dialog, under **Print Setup**, set your wanted Printer paper size.

[image]

Then go to **Page Size** tab, set the page size to **Pre-defined size**, select the proper paper to let the Drawing Page fit the Printer Paper. You can view the preview in right side to check it. For example:

[image]

Click **OK** and check if you can print it correctly.

Comment: Thank you!!! That's one proper answer. It worked perfectly for me.